# Aligning labels of chemical reaction

Tags: chemfig

how do I do this:

[image]

so far I have:

```
\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3Cl}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[.25ex]{\chemfig{Si(Cu)}}{Silicon/CopperAlloy}
\chemrel{->} 
\chembelow[.25ex]{\chemfig{(CH3)_2SiCl2}}{Dimethyldichlorosilane}
\chemsign{+}
\chemfig{Cu}
\schemestop
\end{center}
```

and I got this:
[image]

Comment: You might want to consider using `\chemname` instead of `\chembelow` (it has essentially the same syntax)... you can add line breaks to the name given there with `\\`: `Silicon/\\copper alloy`. The reason the `Cu` and `CH3` look bad is because `()` are used for branches in the `chemfig` syntax. You should look in the `polymers` section of the manual for an idea of how to add parens, but I'm not sure if that's the easiest way. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use stacks to accomplish the underset.  The `\useanchorwidth{T}` option means that the width of the underset text does not affect the equation spacing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3Cl}
\chemsign{+}
\stackunder[18pt]{\chemfig{Si{(}Cu{)}}}{\Longunderstack{Silicon/\\Copper Alloy}}
\chemrel{->} 
\stackunder[18pt]{\chemfig{{(}CH3{)}_2SiCl2}}{Dimethyldichlorosilane}
\chemsign{+}
\chemfig{Cu}
\schemestop
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the "Silicon/Copper Alloy" to be left-aligned, then change that input to `\Longunderstack[l]{Silicon/\\Copper Alloy}` by adding the `[l]` option.

Answer (score 4):

No need an extra package, `\chemname` does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\schemestart
  \chemfig{CH_3Cl}
  \+
  \chemname{\chemfig{Si{(Cu)}}}{Silicon\\/CopperAlloy}
  \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
  \chemname{\chemfig{{(CH3)}_2SiCl2}}{Dimethyldichlorosilane}
  \+
  \chemfig{Cu}
\schemestop
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]