# Aligning Species of a Reaction Horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, chemfig

how do you align the following horizontally:

```
\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chembelow[3ex]{\chemfig{*6(=-=-(-[,.65]OH)=-)}}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[8ex]{\chemfig{CH_2O}}{Formaldehyde}
\arrow{->}
\chembelow[3ex]{\chemfig{*6(=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-=-(-[,.65]OH)=-)}}{Methylolphenol}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[3ex]{\chemfig{*6(=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-=-(-[,.65]OH)=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-)}}    {Dimethylolphenol}
\schemestop
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: An answer with chemfig tool is easy but do not hold your attention. A solution with the stackengine package is probably possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check page 20 of the manual for how to write molecule names properly using `chemname`. There you can also find the alignment methods.

In your case, this should work:

```
\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemnameinit{\chemfig{*6(=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-=-(-[,.65]OH)=-)}}
\chemfig{*6(=-=-(-[,.65]OH)=-)}
\chemsign{+}
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_2O}}{Formaldehyde}
\chemrel{->}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-=-(-[,.65]OH)=-)}}{Methylolphenol}
\chemsign{+}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-=-(-[,.65]OH)=(-[,.65]CH_2OH)-)}}{Dimethylolphenol}
\chemnameinit{}
\schemestop
\end{center}
```

Btw. a similar question is answered here (using different methods): [Aligning labels of chemical reaction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203101/aligning-labels-of-chemical-reaction)